# Too few reviews?

Tags: discussion

I've just checked [review statistics](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/) for SQA.SE and it looks very distressing. Nobody, including diamond moderators, have made more than circa 120 reviews, across all five categories.

Is it okay?
If not, how can it be improved?

Comment: Is it fair to say that the number of reviews is partially a function of the number of questions?

Comment: @user246 Absolutely. Maybe even more: both numbers depend on each other. The better Q&A edited, the more new people tend to stay here (and generate new content). I guess, the core site members know how to attract more ppl here. So my question was mostly about something what's in my power. :)

Answer (score 2):

To be fair, the queues seem to be pretty low-volume around here.

Unless you start seeing items pile up, I'd say the community is doing well at keeping up with the reviews. :)